# ngx-toaster not working properly in inline configuration for lazily loaded child module

Tags: angular, angular9, angular10, ngx-toastr

I am trying to use [ngx-toaste](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-toastr)r in my angular 9+ application in inline mode to show it inside one of the divs. Its working fine in app.component HTML. But working unexpectedly inside lazily loaded child components. It's not coming inside the div but floating somewhere outside the component(Attaching screenshots[image]). Stackblitz link below :

https://stackblitz.com/github/winrp17/testtoaster

Comment: Did you find solution?

Answer (score 0):

The inline mode exists, but is not intended to be used with default styles. You will need to write your own css

Comment: What do you mean by default styles here ?

Comment: The css that is included with ngx-toastr is not meant to be used inline, you will need to create your own or modify it to display inline block

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party but here's my solution for ngx-toastr v18 add this code to any component.

```
import {ToastContainerDirective, ToastrService} from 'ngx-toastr';
@ViewChildren(ToastContainerDirective) inlineContainers: QueryList<ToastContainerDirective>;


options: any;

 constructor( private toastr: ToastrService,) {

    this.options = this.toastr.toastrConfig;}
downloadPdf() {
if (this.dataListTotal < 500) {
  this.toastr.overlayContainer = this.inlineContainers.toArray()[0];
  this.options.preventDuplicates = true;
  this.toastr.warning('Please add a filter!', 'Dataset is too big!', {
    // enableHtml: true,
    positionClass: 'inline',
    tapToDismiss: true,
    disableTimeOut: true,
    closeButton: true,
  });
} else {}
```

And then place toastrDirective on any div in your html - the toaster msg will display under that div - for example:

```
<div class="float-right" toastContainer>
      
      <a class="pdf-button" (click)="downloadPdf()">
        Download PDF
      </a>
    </div>
```

[image]

For app.modules:

```
import {ToastContainerDirective, ToastrModule} from 'ngx-toastr';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AppRoutingModule,  
    ToastrModule.forRoot(),
    ToastContainerDirective,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
```